# Spring Boot initializes context only in the first request when deployed in Websphere Liberty Profile

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere-liberty

Here is the background.
I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot application into Websphere Liberty Profile. 
I have made the required changes in the pom file

1. package as war
2. dependency conflict resolutions to exclude and mark as provided the relevant dependencies
3. changed the main application class to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` and implement `WebApplicationInitializer`.

I then drop the packaged war into the dropins directory of the websphere liberty profile server.

At this moment my expectation is that the application deploys and initializes the context and becomes ready to serve any http requests it gets.

But what happens is I see the following in the log

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9082/sringbootapp/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application sringbootapp started in 8,197 seconds.
```

Which means the server has detected and deployed the application. When I request a service in the application, only then the following log shows up:

```
(Spring Boot Banner)
2016-05-25T16:39:08,454 thrId="[Default Executor-thread-1009]" lLv="INFO" uid="" [[]] jLoc="org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader" jLocL=272 jMess=[[Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8822 ms]]
2016-05-25T16:39:24,993 thrId="[Default Executor-thread-1009]" lLv="INFO" uid="" [[]] jLoc="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter" jLocL=539 jMess=[[Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@65f1bd54: startup date [Wed May 25 16:38:59 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy]]
2016-05-25T16:39:25,673 thrId="[Default Executor-thread-1009]" lLv="INFO" uid="" [[]] jLoc="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" jLocL=534 jMess=[[Mapped "{[/cart/predicate]}" onto public void no.dnb.vaap.querydsl.controller.CartController.getCartUsingQueryDslPredicate()]]
2016-05-25T16:39:25,673 thrId="[Default Executor-thread-1009]" lLv="INFO" uid="" [[]] jLoc="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" jLocL=534 jMess=[[Mapped "{[/cart/query]}" onto public void no.dnb.vaap.querydsl.controller.CartController.getCustomerUsingQueryDslQuery()]]
2016-05-25T16:39:25,720 thrId="[Default Executor-thread-1009]" lLv="INFO" uid="" [[]] jLoc="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" jLocL=534 jMess=[[Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]]
2016-05-25T16:39:25,720 thrId="[Default Executor-thread-1009]" lLv="INFO" uid="" [[]] jLoc="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" jLocL=534 jMess=[[Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]]
2016-05-25T16:39:26,094 thrId="[Default Executor-thread-1009]" lLv="INFO" uid="" [[]] jLoc="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping" jLocL=341 jMess=[[Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]]]
2016-05-25T16:39:26,109 thrId="[Default Executor-thread-1009]" lLv="INFO" uid="" [[]] jLoc="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping" jLocL=341 jMess=[[Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]]]
2016-05-25T16:39:26,376 thrId="[Default Executor-thread-1009]" lLv="INFO" uid="" [[]] jLoc="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping" jLocL=341 jMess=[[Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]]]
2016-05-25T16:39:28,605 thrId="[Default Executor-thread-1009]" lLv="INFO" uid="" [[]] jLoc="org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet" jLocL=487 jMess=[[FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started]]
2016-05-25T16:39:28,672 thrId="[Default Executor-thread-1009]" lLv="INFO" uid="" [[]] jLoc="org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet" jLocL=506 jMess=[[FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 67 ms]]
```

Now this means, the spring context was initialized only now, during the first request after the app was deployed.

Has anyone faced this issue? Did I miss something?

My pom file

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>no.dnb.amn</groupId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<artifactId>querydsl</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.2</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>

<plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
             <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <classifier>apt</classifier>
            <version>3.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
        </plugin> 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

My Main Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

WLP server.xml

```
<server description="new server">

<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
<httpEndpoint httpPort="9082" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

<!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
<applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>
<include location="xsServerConfig.xml"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem. The answer is to specify:

```
<webContainer deferServletLoad="false"/>
```

See:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCKBL_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_servlet_load.html

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot in a Container needs Servlet-3.0.
As you didn't name that feature explicitly in your server.xml this might be a case.
Add it, as described here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_setup_feat.html

`<featureManager>
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    ...
</featureManager>`

Next, I would try adding the WAR as an application-entry and not dropped via the dropins-directory, described here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dep_war.html

`<application context-root="helloworld" type="war" id="helloworld"
    location="helloworld.war" name="helloworld"/>`

where *location* must point to your war.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But the issue still persists.

Comment: 1. I added the servlet-3.0 feature in the server.xml
2. Added the application element as well

The logs just says the web application is available at http://localhost:port/blabla .... But the spring context is initialized only at the first hit on the application.

I deployed the same application war in a Websphere Application Server ND 8.5.5.9  . It worked like a charm springing the context alive on deployment. 

WAS Liberty is where the issue persists.